# Global code coverage in multi-module Android project: merge code coverage reports (Unit & UI tests)

Tags: android, jacoco, android-espresso

I have an Android app which is made up of 2 modules:

- App - UI
- Submodule - has most of the business logic

For each of them I have a gradle task to validate code coverage:

- App: UI Code coverage (Espresso)
- Submodule: Unit tests code coverage

As a requirement for the client, **I need to merge those two reports to get the overall/global code coverage** of the app.

Note: I'm using **Gradle version 3.1.2.**

---

### App Gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'jacoco'

android {

   testBuildType "uiTest"

    ...

  buildTypes {
    debug {
        applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
        versionNameSuffix "-debug"
        debuggable true

        minifyEnabled false
        shrinkResources false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'


        matchingFallbacks = ['debug']
    }

    // TESTS

    // unitTest will be used to run unit tests.
    unitTest.initWith(buildTypes.debug) //Beware the buildType this depends on MUST be above on the gradle file
    unitTest {
        applicationIdSuffix ".unitTest"
        versionNameSuffix "-unitTest"

        testCoverageEnabled = true
        matchingFallbacks = ['unitTest', 'debug']
    }

    // uiTest will be used to run ui tests.
    uiTest.initWith(buildTypes.debug) //Beware the buildType this depends on MUST be above on the gradle file
    uiTest {
        applicationIdSuffix ".uiTest"
        versionNameSuffix "-uiTest"

        testCoverageEnabled = true
        matchingFallbacks = ['uiTest', 'debug']
    }

    ...
```

### SubModule Gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'jacoco'

android {

   testBuildType "uiTest"

   buildTypes {
    debug {
    }

    unitTest {
        initWith(buildTypes.debug)
        testCoverageEnabled = true
    }

    uiTest {
        initWith(buildTypes.debug)
        testCoverageEnabled = true
    }

  ...
}
```

I've tried several ways, this one below indeed merges the tests.. but the coverage is not appearing correctly:

### **The task for creating UI Test coverage in the app:**

//UI Test Coverage filtered (we need to run unit tests of App to be able to use Jacoco to filter)

```
task createTestReport(type: JacocoReport, dependsOn: [':app:testUnitTestUnitTest', ':app:createUiTestAndroidTestCoverageReport']) {

reports {
    html.enabled = true
}

def fileFilter = [
        //Android stuff
        '**/R.class',
        '**/BR.class',
        '**/R$*.class',
        '**/BR$*.class',
        '**/BuildConfig.*',
        'android/**/*.*',
        //Data Binding
        '**/*databinding',
        '**/*binders',
        '**/*layouts',
        '**/Manifest*.*',
        '**/*Test*.*',
        "**/services/**/model/**",
        //Utils
        '**/utils/*.*',
        '**/utils/**/*.*'
]

//To support Java coverage on Unit tests
def debugTree = fileTree(dir: "${buildDir}/intermediates/classes/unitTest", excludes: fileFilter)
//To support Kotlin coverage on Unit tests
def kotlinDebugTree = fileTree(dir: "${buildDir}/tmp/kotlin-classes/unitTest", excludes: fileFilter)

def mainSrc = "${project.projectDir}/src/main/java"
def debugSrc = "${project.projectDir}/src/debug/java"

sourceDirectories = files([mainSrc, debugSrc])


def appAndroidTests = fileTree(dir: "${buildDir}/outputs/code-coverage/connected/", includes: ["**/*.ec"])
def appOtherAndroidTests = fileTree(dir: "${buildDir}/outputs/androidTest-results/connected/", includes: ["**/*.ec"])

classDirectories = files([debugTree], [kotlinDebugTree])
executionData = files("${buildDir}/jacoco/testUnitTestUnitTest.exec", appAndroidTests, appOtherAndroidTests)
```

}

### **The task for creating Unit test coverage in the sub-module:**

//Unit Test Coverage filtered

task createTestReport(type: JacocoReport, dependsOn: ['testUnitTestUnitTest']) {

```
reports {
    html.enabled = true
}

def fileFilter = ['**/R.class',
                  '**/BR.class',
                  '**/R$*.class',
                  '**/BR$*.class',
                  '**/BuildConfig.*',
                  '**/*databinding/**/*.*',
                  '**/Manifest*.*',
                  '**/*Test*.*',
                  "**/services/**/model/**",
                  'android/**/*.*',
                  '**/utils/*.*',
                  '**/utils/**/*.*']

//To support Java coverage on Unit tests
def debugTree = fileTree(dir: "${buildDir}/intermediates/classes/unitTest", excludes: fileFilter)
//To support Kotlin coverage on Unit tests
def kotlinDebugTree = fileTree(dir: "${buildDir}/tmp/kotlin-classes/unitTest", excludes: fileFilter)

def mainSrc = "${project.projectDir}/src/main/java"
def debugSrc = "${project.projectDir}/src/debug/java"

sourceDirectories = files([mainSrc, debugSrc])


classDirectories = files([debugTree], [kotlinDebugTree])
executionData = files("${buildDir}/jacoco/testUnitTestUnitTest.exec")
```

}

### **The task for creating Global coverage in the app:**

//Global Test Coverage

task createGlobalTestReport(type: JacocoReport,
        dependsOn: [':app:testUnitTestUnitTest', ':app:createTestReport',
                    ':submodule:testUnitTestUnitTest']) {

```
reports {
    html.enabled = true
}

def fileFilter = [
        //Android stuff
        '**/R.class',
        '**/BR.class',
        '**/R$*.class',
        '**/BR$*.class',
        '**/BuildConfig.*',
        'android/**/*.*',
        //Data Binding
        '**/*databinding',
        '**/*binders',
        '**/*layouts',
        '**/Manifest*.*',
        '**/*Test*.*',
        "**/services/**/model/**",
        //Utils
        '**/utils/*.*',
        '**/utils/**/*.*'
]

// Note: **/reviews/ReviewService*.* was added as BazaarVoice cannot be mocked

//To support Java coverage on Unit tests
def debugAppTree = fileTree(dir: "${buildDir}/intermediates/classes/unitTest", excludes: fileFilter)
//To support Kotlin coverage on Unit tests
def debugKotlinAppTree = fileTree(dir: "${buildDir}/tmp/kotlin-classes/unitTest", excludes: fileFilter)

def debugSdkTree = fileTree(dir: "..//build/intermediates/classes/unitTest", excludes: fileFilter)
def debugKotlinSdkTree = fileTree(dir: "../submodule/build/tmp/kotlin-classes/unitTest", excludes: fileFilter)


def mainAppSrc = "${project.projectDir}/src/main/java"
def debugAppSrc = "${project.projectDir}/src/debug/java"

def mainSdkSrc = "../submodule/src/main/java"
def debugSdkSrc = "../submodule/src/debug/java"


sourceDirectories = files([mainAppSrc, debugAppSrc,
                           mainSdkSrc, debugSdkSrc])


def appAndroidTests = fileTree(dir: "${buildDir}/outputs/code-coverage/connected/", includes: ["**/*.ec"])
def sdkAndroidTests = fileTree(dir: "../submodule/build/outputs/code-coverage/connected/", includes: ["**/*.ec"])

classDirectories = files([debugAppTree, debugSdkTree,
                          debugKotlinAppTree, debugKotlinSdkTree])
executionData = files("${buildDir}/jacoco/testUnitTestUnitTest.exec"
        , "../submodule/build/jacoco/testUnitTestUnitTest.exec"
        , appAndroidTests
        , sdkAndroidTests
)
```

}

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure it works with multiple build types.

Try merging it into a single build type and:

### App Gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'jacoco'
android {
   testBuildType "automationTest"
    ...
  buildTypes {
    debug {
        applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
        versionNameSuffix "-debug"
        debuggable true
        minifyEnabled false
        shrinkResources false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

        matchingFallbacks = ['debug']
    }
    // TESTS
    automationTest {
        applicationIdSuffix ".automationTest"
        versionNameSuffix "-automationTest"

        testCoverageEnabled = true
        matchingFallbacks = ['automationTest', 'debug']
    }
    ...
```

### SubModule Gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'jacoco'
android {

   buildTypes {
    debug {
    }

    automationTest {
        initWith(buildTypes.debug)
        testCoverageEnabled = true
    }

    release {
        initWith(buildTypes.debug)
    }
  ...
}
```

### **The task for creating Unit test coverage in the sub-module:**

```
task createUnitTestReport(type: JacocoReport, dependsOn: ['testAutomationTestUnitTest']) {

reports {
    html.enabled = true
}

def fileFilter = ['**/R.class',
                  '**/BR.class',
                  '**/R$*.class',
                  '**/BR$*.class',
                  '**/BuildConfig.*',
                  '**/*databinding/**/*.*',
                  '**/Manifest*.*',
                  '**/*Test*.*',
                  'android/**/*.*']

//To support Java coverage on Unit tests
def debugTree = fileTree(dir: "${buildDir}/intermediates/classes/automationTest", excludes: fileFilter)
//To support Kotlin coverage on Unit tests
def kotlinDebugTree = fileTree(dir: "${buildDir}/tmp/kotlin-classes/automationTest", excludes: fileFilter)

def mainSrc = "${project.projectDir}/src/main/java"
def debugSrc = "${project.projectDir}/src/debug/java"

sourceDirectories = files([mainSrc, debugSrc])


classDirectories = files([debugTree], [kotlinDebugTree])
executionData = files("${buildDir}/jacoco/testAutomationTestUnitTest.exec")
}
```

### **The task for creating Global coverage in the app:**

```
task createGlobalTestReport(type: JacocoReport,
    dependsOn: [':app:createUiTestReport', ':submodule:createUnitTestReport']) {

reports {
    html.enabled = true
}

def fileFilter = [
        //Android stuff
        '**/R.class',
        '**/BR.class',
        '**/R$*.class',
        '**/BR$*.class',
        '**/BuildConfig.*',
        'android/**/*.*',
        //Data Binding
        '**/*databinding',
        '**/*binders',
        '**/*layouts',
        '**/Manifest*.*',
        '**/*Test*.*'
]

//To support Java coverage on Unit tests
def debugAppTree = fileTree(dir: "${buildDir}/intermediates/classes/automationTest", excludes: fileFilter)
//To support Kotlin coverage on Unit tests
def debugKotlinAppTree = fileTree(dir: "${buildDir}/tmp/kotlin-classes/automationTest", excludes: fileFilter)

def debugSdkTree = fileTree(dir: "../submodule/build/intermediates/classes/automationTest", excludes: fileFilter)
def debugKotlinSdkTree = fileTree(dir: "../submodule/build/tmp/kotlin-classes/automationTest", excludes: fileFilter)


def mainAppSrc = "${project.projectDir}/src/main/java"
def debugAppSrc = "${project.projectDir}/src/debug/java"

def mainSdkSrc = "../submodule/src/main/java"
def debugSdkSrc = "../submodule/src/debug/java"


sourceDirectories = files([mainAppSrc, debugAppSrc,
                           mainSdkSrc, debugSdkSrc])

classDirectories = files([debugAppTree, debugSdkTree,
                          debugKotlinAppTree, debugKotlinSdkTree])

def appAndroidTests = fileTree(dir: "${buildDir}/outputs/code-coverage/connected/", includes: ["*.ec"])

executionData = files("${buildDir}/jacoco/testAutomationTestUnitTest.exec"
        , "../submodule/build/jacoco/testAutomationTestUnitTest.exec"
        , appAndroidTests
)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use a plugin by palantir to create aggregate coverage reports for my different modules - [com.palantir.jacoco-full-report](https://github.com/palantir/gradle-jacoco-coverage)

Basically, in your root gradle file, you need to add this in your dependencies:

`classpath 'com.palantir:jacoco-coverage:0.4.0'`

After that, when you run  `./gradlew test jacocoFullReport` a test report in `build/reports/jacoco/jacocoFullReport/` that evaluates the coverage yielded by all subprojects combined is created.

Comment: "Note: This plugin is considered obsolete as of Gradle 3.4 which supports coverage enforcement as part of the core JaCoCo plugin."

Comment: jacoco-coverage has been deprecated, but you can still use the jacoco-full-report plugin, That is not yet part of gradle. Perhaps, you can elaborate further any specific scenario that is not covered by it for you.

Comment: I was looking for an option that didn't meant using deprecated things..